# introductory probability Q

Tags: probability

john is taking a multiple choice test which consists of 8 questions, each question is has 4 possible answers with only one correct. Find the probability that the final answer given is the 6th one that is correct.

I tried a few things, here is one:

we have that the final one is the 6th one that is correct, so the previous 7 must have had 5 right answers, so i figure the answer is $${ 7 \choose 5 } \left(\frac{1}{4} \right)^5\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^2 + something$$ that something I figure is the probability that the last one is correct - but i am unsure how to express this.

is my method correct and how do I figure out "something"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $E$ be the event you described ($6$th correct answer is on last question)

As you have stated, you need the probability of $5$ correct out of the previous $7$ given by 
$${ 7 \choose 5 } \left(\frac{1}{4} \right)^5\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^2$$.

Let's call this event A. His ability to guess the answer to the last question properly is independent of his previous answer history, because of this $P(S|A) = P(S) = \frac14$ where S is the event that he gets the 8th question correct.

Therefore,
$$P(E) = P(A \cap S) = P(S|A)P(A) = P(S)P(A) = \frac14 { 7 \choose 5 } \left(\frac{1}{4} \right)^5\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^2$$

Answer (score 1):

Choose $5$ out of the first $7$ questions to be correct.

Choose the remaining $2$ questions to be incorrect.

Choose the last question to be correct.

---

$$\binom75\cdot\left(\frac14\right)^5\cdot\binom22\cdot\left(\frac34\right)^2\cdot\binom11\cdot\left(\frac14\right)^1=\frac{189}{65536}$$